# <h:inputText> executes focus listener only if validation has passed in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I have the following view:

VIEW:

```
<div class="#{formAccountRegister.formTest}">
    <h:inputText id="field-firstname" value="#{formAccountRegister.account.person.firstName}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{account['validate.required']}" styleClass="#{ component.valid ? 'default' : 'default error'}">
        <f:validator validatorId="validatorNameFirst"/>
        <f:ajax event="focus" listener="#{formAccountRegister.changeIt(event)}"/>
        <f:ajax event="blur" render="field-firstname message-firstname"/>
    </h:inputText>
</div>
```

I would like to do change the `class` of the `div` when the `input` gains `focus`. Everything works fine, but only if the validation has passed. If the validation has not passed the method `chageIt(event)` does not execute. I use `Mojarra v2.2.7`.

How can I make it work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSF has 6 life cycle phases http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSFIntro10.html

In that third one is the `Validation` phase. If the validation is succeeded then only the subsequent phases `Update Modal Values`(4th) and `Invoke Application Phase`(5th) will be executed. Since the validation is failed then the 4th and 5th phases are skipped and directly `Render response`(6th) phase is executed. That's why your listener on focus event is not called which is supposed to be executed in 5th phase and it is the expected behaviour according to jsf framework.

If you want to change the CSS then you could use `onfocus` attribute of `<h:inputText>` and do it on the client side.

Hope this helps.